# Converting Java applet to web application

Tags: java, web-applications

I would like to convert [this Java applet](http://ford.ieor.berkeley.edu/grip/) into an equivalent web app. This is my first time creating a web app, but I have some programming experience and time, and am willing to teach myself all of the necessary tools.

By "web app", I mean an application which would work in browsers without requiring Java or Flash, for example. Therefore, it could work on compatible mobile devices.

What tools should I look into for this development project?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: yep like Holger says the answer is java script and Canvas the new HTML 5 element. many tutorials out there in search engines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The critical part seems to be the drawing. This might be a use case for HTML5 Canvas, at least what I can tell from the screenshot (I cannot run Applet). WebGL might also be an option if 3D Graphics is of interest.

As with everything javascript related there are plenty frameworks available or you can follow HTML5 tutorials.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas

or you can resort to frameworks like http://kineticjs.com/

If you want to check out possibilities with HTML5 you can look at Mozilla's HTML5 demos:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/demos/tag/tech:html5

For the User interface I would suggest using a UI Toolkit like Google Closure since you really don't want to start your own interface toolkit.